# Spring MVC HandlerInterceptorAdapter Missing slf4j Logback Trace ID

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, logback, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have Spring MVC Application where I have implemented a class which extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter for me to perform some operations inside preHandle, postHandle and afterCompletion before any controller gets executed. below is what I am observing.

**Log Entry for preHandle logging**
AppTime: 00:30:01.230 | Thread: [http-nio-8080-exec-1] | Level: INFO  | Class: hello.extractor | X-Span-Export=false, X-B3-SpanId=3aad3f52e26eb59d, X-B3-TraceId=3aad3f52e26eb59d | Msg: Inside preHandle

**Log Entry for postHandle logging**
AppTime: 00:30:01.394 | Thread: [http-nio-8080-exec-1] | Level: INFO  | Class: hello.extractor | X-Span-Export=false, X-B3-SpanId=3aad3f52e26eb59d, X-B3-TraceId=3aad3f52e26eb59d | Msg: Inside postHandle

**Log Entry for afterCompletionlogging**
AppTime: 00:30:01.395 | Thread: [http-nio-8080-exec-1] | Level: INFO  | Class: hello.extractor |  | Msg: Inside afterCompletion.

if you see the third entry is missing trace ID and Span ID. Any idea on how to resolve this?

public class Extractor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

```
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpHeaderExtractor.class);

@Autowired
public Extractor() {
}

public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {

    logger.info("Inside preHandle");
    return true;
}

public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Inside postHandle");
}

public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
        throws Exception {
    logger.info("Inside afterCompletion");
}
```

}

Comment: show your code for `HandlerInterceptorAdapter ` and corresponding log configuration

Comment: Can you post your full sample somewhere? You have the same thread but obviously it seems that the `afterCompletion` of the `TraceHandlerInterceptor` has closed the span before it reached your handler. You'd have to ensure that your interceptor is executed before the `TraceHandlerInterceptor`. But without seeing the sample these are just my assumptions.

Comment: Hello. I have added sample code. @MarcinGrzejszczak

Comment: Can you post it somewhere on GitHub ? THat way I'll be able to see exactly how you're setting up the configuration, logging etc.

Comment: Hi @MarcinGrzejszczak Thank you for spending time on this question. I found that we had added another HandlerIntercepter which was doing MDC Logging and inside in it we were manually clearing which is causing not to populate trace id in my another HandlerIntercepter aftercompletion method.

Comment: Ah good to know! Thanks a lot for the answer :) Could you please answer it here so that we don't have an answered question? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that we had added another HandlerIntercepter which was doing MDC Logging and inside in it we were manually clearing which is causing not to populate trace id in my another HandlerIntercepter aftercompletion method. Also if you are using multiple handler interceptors and the sequence you register matters. In latest spring, you will have declare them in reverse order for them execute one by one.